# Изменение рабочей папки проекта .Net Framework API

Tags: c#, .net, iis

Возникла проблема при работе с проектом на .net framework 4.7.2. Поскольку для дебага там используется IIS Express, соответственно

```
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
```

Возвращает место, где находится iis, а мне нужно, чтобы рабочая папка была там, где находится проект. Каким образом это можно сделать, если изменить опции дебага, по аналогии с .net core проектом, невозможно?

Comment: Зачем вам это нужно?

Comment: Мне необходимо, чтобы файлы, которые генерируются в процессе работы приложения, находились в той же папке, в которой находится .exe файл

Comment: о каком exe файле вы пишете, если у вас сайт на IIS?